# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 C++ --- Press any key to continue on a new line?

Tags: c++

Whenever I print something to the screen, the line: "Press any key to continue" shows up right after without a line break. For example if I am printing "Hello World", the cmd will print out Hello WordPress any key to continue. Any way for that dialogue to skip a line?

I understand this is a really silly thing to be messing around with but it feels kinda annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: Change your code to cout << "Hello world!\n"

Comment: cout << "Hello world!\n", not Cout ;)

Comment: It is giving you a chance to look at the console output you generated before letting it close.  Helpful to avoid having to read it in less than 10 milliseconds.  Start debugging your program by pressing F5, you won't get the "Press any key" delay.

Comment: My phone auto-corrected @jensa

Comment: I never use auto-correct, I like to think I know better than my phone :)

Comment: as the other commenters mentioned, you need to print a new line character at the end of your sentence. You can just add "\n" to the sentence you want to print, or if you are using C++ and `cout`, add `std::cout << std::endl;` after printing your sentence.

Comment: @HansPassant Does this really work? I thought F5 just ran through it all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing to the stream you have to tell the stream when you want a newline.  If you always want to make sure there is a newline before "press any key" then you can use the newline escape sequence `'\n'`

```
std::cout << "\nPlease enter any key to continue...";
```

Alternatively you can write a newline at then end of every output like

```
std::cout << "This is a line\n";
//or
std::cout << "this is a line" << std::endl;
```

Using `endl` will also flush the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put an empty WriteLine under your last line.

```
Console::WriteLine("");
```